# How to update columns only if argument is equal to specific value?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, coldfusion, sybase

I have query that should update columns only if argument is equal 1. Here is example:

```
<cfquery name="updateQry" datasource="test">
    UPDATE Table1
    SET fname = form.fname,
        lname = form.lname,
        <cfif form.status eq 1>
            title = form.title,
        </cfif>
        last_update_dt = getDate()
    WHERE rec_id = form.record_id
 </cfquery>
```

I would like to move this SQL query to stored procedure. How I can achive the same process with SQL code only? Instead of `<cfif form.status eq 1> title = @title,</cfif>` how that can be replaced with SQL code? I use Sybase database and ColdFusion 2016. This code above should be moved to stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want a `case` expression, something like this:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET fname = form.fname,
    lname = form.lname,
    title = (case when form.status = 1 then form.title else table1.title end),
    last_update_dt = getDate()
WHERE rec_id = form.record_id;
```

In a stored procedure, you would probably use parameters:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET fname = @fname,
    lname = @lname,
    title = (case when @status = 1 then @title else table1.title end),
    last_update_dt = getDate()
WHERE rec_id = #record_id;
```

Comment: In your example `title` column will be updated every time no matter what. In case when `form.status` is equal 1 then `title` column should be updated.

Comment: @espresso_coffee . . . One of us is missing something.  When `status` is anything other than `1`, then the value is set back to its value -- that is a no-op.  Nothing changes in the column.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that piece. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.